# Capturing 404s when using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to track down some unexpected 404s in a hybrid WordPress/custom code site. Since the 404s are redirected I'm not seeing the original request in the access_logs.

What is a good way to track these given WordPress' rewrite_rules are in the mix?

.htaccess is just WP

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Just pasting the default WordPress htaccess isn't going to qualify as "attempted a solution" in my opinion

Comment: STT LCU Yes- I pulled the access_log and looked for 404s and finding none deduced that mod_rewrite was preventing them.  Then I Googled the words I used as the title of my post and not finding any answers that way I'm asking my peers if they have knowledge of a good way to handle this.

Comment: The htaccess was merely provided so folks would know there wasn't anything special about it.

Comment: I wasn't accusing. It actually enhances the quality of the question if you say what you tried, alongside with any relevant code. Maybe you're wrong with your deduction of a 404 prevention, or you're right. Nevertheless it's a bit of information more than before, which can narrow the research field and focus the answers. I'm not keen on wordpress, but I'd say that the 404 the site is throwing aren't "real" 404 from apache but rather generated by the wordpress core. See? One bit of info -> More focused advice.

Comment: Well since the htaccess is rewriting everything that does not exist as a file or folder to index.php, the “not found” errors would have to be handled there. And even if wordpress does that (displaying an appropriate message and sending a 404 status code), you will not find those 404s in the apache log any more. But doesn’t wordpress have some logs of its own where you can find the requests that resulted in not found errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy to install a plugin, something like the [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin might help (disclaimer - I've never used it).

Failing that, you could try hooking the [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action and logging the `$_SERVER` info if [`is_404()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_404) returns true.